# Variable or pattern name for method arguments as both input and output parameter

Tags: variables, design-patterns, naming

When I have an ecryption method parameter that acts as an input and output parameter, is there a convention on how to name such parameters? Or, more general, when I have a method that completely rewrites the content of an argument, is there a convention? Or is there a name for this pattern?

The name or pattern should

- either represent the fact that the variable contains unencrypted content before and encrypted content after the call
- or, more general, make it obvious that the method will put its result into the parameter, which will have different content afterwards -- the content will not be slightly altered, but completely rewritten.

Compare to Botan::Cipher_Mode::finish() https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1Cipher__Mode.html they just call the method `final_block` and explain `final_block    in/out parameter which must be [...]`.

I only came up with in_out, but this is not really satisfying.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters